# Change to other space (MacOSX) programmatically

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nswindow

I am making a customised window (a NSWindow with NSBorderlessWindowMask) So far I have been able to handle dragging, resizing, cmd+click and even miniaturize with double click if allowed (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099338/how-to-know-if-window-is-minimizable-when-titlebar-was-double-clicked)) so my window resembles as much as possible to a normal NSWindow.

However when I drag my window to the corner of my screen the user will expect to move that window to the next space. (In case you have Spaces enabled in "SystemPreferences" > "Expose and Spaces" > "Spaces" > "Enable Spaces")

I wonder how can I change to other space programmatically and move my window there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found a solution.
I can't change to a certain space programmatically but I can make my window behave like other non `NSBorderlessWindowMask` if `[window setMovableByWindowBackground:YES]` is done. That was the final purpose of this question :)

The solution is written (*with some detail*) here because that question seems to be older (*or maybe a duplicate of this question?*)

[Is there a way to make a custom NSWindow work with Spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694582/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-custom-nswindow-work-with-spaces/6847930#6847930)

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately there's no public API which allows you to do this, but if you're willing to use the Private API it's possible. Take a look at [CGSPrivate.h](https://github.com/shabble/osx-space-id/blob/master/CGSPrivate.h) and you'll see you can make a call like this:

```
CGSConnection connection = _CGSDefaultConnection();
CGSMoveWorkspaceWindowList(connection, &windowNumber, 1, newSpaceNumber);
```

Note that using this private API will cause your app to be rejected from Apple's Mac App Store though.