# How to programmatically move a space left or right in macOS?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I'm developing a menubar application and want to be able to move between spaces just like the shortcut `control + side arrows` does.

I've already searched `NSWindow` and `NSWorkspace` classes but didn't find anything.

Edit:
I do not have a window that I want to make full screen in a new space. I just want to move between existing spaces.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change to other space (MacOSX) programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6250864/change-to-other-space-macosx-programmatically)

Comment: Edited to explain how my question is different.

Comment: @adrianokw - Look at the answers to the question matt linked, one of them answers your question - there is no public API to do this.